# php elastica: how to set username / password?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

I'm using `ruflin/elastica 6.0.1` library, but didn't find a way to set username / password params for connection.

I've tried to set it in host url like this:

`https://username:password@host.com`

but it did not work.

Is there a way to set username / password in elastica?

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been added by [PR#1030](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/pull/1030), There are some code usage in test cases, You can create an associate array contains `username` and `password` then pass into `Elastica\Client::__construct()`.

```
<?php

use Elastica\Client;

$config = [
    'host' => 'host.com',
    'username' => 'john doe',
    'password' => 's3cret',
];
$client = new Client($config);
```